# Show text as selected in a dropdown using its value in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am getting `id` from the `URL` using the code given below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var full_url = document.URL; // Get current url
var url_array = full_url.split('/') // Split the string into an array with / as separator
var last_segment = url_array[url_array.length-2];  // Returns Id
```

This `id` is one the value of options in select box

```
Ex:- <option value="37">xxx</option>
```

Now, I want to show the text related to this `id` as selected. How can i do this using jQuery?

I have tried this:

```
$("#field-projectId option[value=last_segment]")).val(last_segment).attr("selected", "true");

$("#field-projectId option[value=last_segment]").attr("selected", "selected");

$("#field-projectId").val(last_segment);
```

Comment: Your last attempt should work. Have you verified that the value of `last_segment` is what you expect? Have you verified that the code is executed at all? Have you verified that `$('#field-projectId')` finds your dropdown?

Comment: Yes, the value in last segment is what i am expecting, now i jus want to show it as selected.

Comment: Have you verified the other assumptions? [Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/9DEkL/), when the assumptions are valid.

Comment: Have you ensured that the "last_segment" value doesn't have any trailing or leading spaces, which might cause the value not to match the drop down value?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
     $('#ddlWeeklyWeightIn').on("change", function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
```

Please refer Demo Link [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/SRq9g/)